# Can adjusted R squared be used to interpret a simple regression using a small sample

Tags: regression, r-squared

In a study with a small sample (n=83) the data were determined to be non normal, Non parametric measures were use and correlations were found between  shared decision making in interdisciplinary teams and  educational attainment coordination in interdisciplinary teams based on respondents’ years in their practice. Two separate simple linear regressions were conducted; one to predict views of shared decision making in interdisciplinary teams based on respondents educational level, and the second to predict views of coordination in interdisciplinary teams based on respondents’ years in their practice. The adjusted R squared was used to interpret the results. The question is can you use adjusted R squared for interpreting simple regression to correct for the small sample size?  While the data was found to be non-normal I thought that simple linear regressions are robust enough to not be affected by non-normality. The issue of adjusted R squared and the use of two separate simple linear regressions are being questioned. i am trying to find any literature to support these decisions.

Comment: I cannot seem to access the title to edit. Thank you for pointing this out. It is cut off. Apparently it was too wordy

Comment: Adjusted R-squared is never used to "correct for small sample size": it corrects for *the number of regressors*, not the number of observations.